# Epsilon-N proofs for Sequence Convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that the following sequences converge:

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2n-\pi}\right\}$$

$$\left\{\frac{\cos(n^2)}{n^2-2}\right\}$$

$$\left\{\frac{1-n^2+n^3}{n^3-1}\right\}$$

I am able to find the values that each sequence converges to but when I begin to do my proofs, I am getting confused as to how to deal with the bounding and cases when sequence is positive vs when it is negative. For example, the first sequence is positive when $n > \pi/2$ but then there is also the negative case, so how would I account for choosing N when completing my proof?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to provide multiple examples, just in case I wasn't being clear. I thought it would make my question more clear since I believe all 3 require a choosing of N that is similar.

Comment: Sorry, just that it comes across to us as though you want us to prove, *for you*, that all three sequences converge.  Again, please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the first problem.  We need to show that for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N>0$ such that

$$\left|\frac1{2n-\pi}\right|<\epsilon$$

whenever $n>N$.  Proceeding we take $N>2$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac1{2n-\pi}\right|&=\frac{1}{2n-\pi}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>\frac12\left(\pi+\frac1\epsilon \right)$.  So, if we let $N=\max\left(2,\frac12\left(\pi+\frac1\epsilon\right)\right)$, we have found an $N$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: could you please explain why you have to choose the max of the values for N? I follow everything up until that point.

Comment: @angelmariogallegos I've edited the typo.  Thank you for the catch.

Comment: @learning_maniac. Sure.  We would like to bound our candidate for $N$ away from the values of $n$ that render $2n-\pi$ negative.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to approach the last problem. First work out what the limit should be. In your given expression divide both numerator and denominator by the highest power of $n$ appearing in the denominator, $viz. n^3.$ $$\frac{1-n^3+n^2}{n^3-1}=\frac{\frac {1}{n^3}-\frac {1}{n}+1}{1-\frac {1}{n^3}}.$$ As $n \rightarrow \infty$, both the numerator and denominator approach 1, so the limit of the expression is 1, but you must $show$ this fact by exhibiting, for any $\epsilon >0$, a natural number $M$ such that $|1-\text { given expression }|<\epsilon$ wenever $n > M.$
 $$|1-\text { given expression }|=\frac {|\frac {-2}{n^3}+\frac {1}{n}|}{|1-\frac {1}{n^3}|}.$$ If  $\frac {1}{n^3}<\frac {1}{2}$ then $|1-\frac {1}{n^3}|=1-\frac {1}{n^3}>\frac {1}{2}$ and $$ \frac {1}{|1-\frac {1}{n^3}|}<2.$$ Note that if $n>2$ then $n^3>8$ and thus $\frac {1}{n^3}<\frac {1}{8}<\frac {1}{2}.$ Now we look at the numerator. We can make $\frac {2}{n^3}<\frac {\epsilon}{5}$ by making $n>(10/\epsilon)^{1/3}$. Let $M_1=\lceil (10/\epsilon)^{1/3} \rceil.$ Let $M_2=\lceil \frac {5}{\epsilon}\rceil.$ Let $M=\max (2,M1,M2). $ If $n>M$ then $n>2, n>M_1 \text { and } n>M_2,$ so $|\frac {-2}{n^3}+\frac {1}{n}| \le |\frac {-2}{n^3}|+|\frac {1}{n}|<\epsilon/5+\epsilon/5=2\epsilon/5$ and $$|1-\text { given expression }|<2 \times 2\epsilon/5=4 \epsilon/5<\epsilon.$$